# How to Magento cron setup

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have Magento 1.9. community edition running. I want to run product export automatically using datafeedmanager. I have setup cron jon in datafeed manager but cron is not running.
Please help me to how to run cron on magento?

Comment: how did u set up the cron.can you share the code ?

Comment: How have you confirmed cron is not running?

Comment: Data feed manager is a paid extension, if no one was to answer your question here, please refer to the devs.

Answer (score 1):

From their website they have two tutorials for this purpose.

The first link shows you how to configure this:-

- https://www.wyomind.com/data-feed-manager-magento.html?directlink=faq#How_to_schedule_my_data_feed_generation_with_Data_Feed_Manager

And the second link shows you how to troubleshoot the issue:-

- https://www.wyomind.com/data-feed-manager-magento.html?directlink=faq#How_do_I_fix_the_issues_with_scheduled_tasks

You need to make sure that Magento's "cron.php" is being configured in your server as Data Feed Manager seem to rely on it to run schedules.